Steam reviews on Apex Legends via Steam Web API
I sometimes collect steam reviews using Steam Web API for personal use, and the following code, while having some redundant parts, can collect all reviews for a given game. Lately I have attempted collecting reviews for Apex Legends, however no matter what I do I get 1427 reviews. I have attempted many things such as removing the language filter, changing off topic activity filter, making the end date dynamic, however I cannot seem to collect all reviews.
After the cursor that yields 27 reviews (which is the first time I get anything but 100) next cursor is AoJwq+Kw1PUCf/CWrQI= and it yields 0 reviews and is also returned as the next cursor.
My code is as follows, is there any suggestions so I can collect all reviews, thank you in advance.
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.parse
import time
 
def fetch_game_reviews(appid, cursor='*', filter='recent', language='english'):
    """
    Fetch game reviews for a specific Steam game.
 
    Parameters:
    - appid: Steam Application ID for the game.
    - cursor: Cursor for pagination. Use '*' for the first page.
    - filter: Type of reviews to fetch ('recent', 'updated', 'all').
    - language: Language of the reviews ('english', 'spanish', etc.).
 
    Returns:
    - JSON response containing game reviews.
    """
    if cursor != '*':
        cursor = urllib.parse.quote(cursor)
    url = f"https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/{appid}?json=1&cursor={cursor}&filter={filter}&language={language}&num_per_page=100&filter_offtopic_activity=0"
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()
 
def fetch_reviews_until_date(appid, end_date, filter='recent', language='all'):
    """
    Fetch game reviews for a specific Steam game until a specific date.
 
    Parameters:
    - appid: Steam Application ID for the game.
    - end_date: The end date for fetching reviews (YYYY-MM-DD format).
    - filter: Type of reviews to fetch ('recent', 'updated', 'all').
    - language: Language of the reviews ('english', 'spanish', etc.).
 
    Returns:
    - List of all reviews up until the specified end date.
    """
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    previous_cursor = None
    all_reviews = []
    cursors = []
    cursor = '*'
    while True:
        response = fetch_game_reviews(appid, cursor=cursor, filter=filter, language=language)
        collected_timestamp = int(time.time())
        reviews = response['reviews']
        new_cursor = response.get('cursor')
        cursors.append(new_cursor)
 
        if not reviews or (new_cursor == previous_cursor and cursor != '*'):
            return all_reviews, cursors  
 
        for review in reviews:
            review_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(review['timestamp_created'])
            review['collected'] = collected_timestamp
            review['appid'] = appid
            if review_date < end_date:
                return all_reviews
            all_reviews.append(review)
            print(len(all_reviews))
            print(response['cursor'])
 
        previous_cursor = cursor
        cursor = new_cursor
 
    return all_reviews, cursors
 
reviews, cursors = fetch_reviews_until_date('1172470', '2020-10-01')


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

you have wrong indentations. You have print() inside for-loop - so it displays the same value for every review on list. You should display it outside for-loop

in question you could add link to this page on Steam - maybe it has only 1427 reviews.

maybe Steam has some problems on server and you have to wait until they fix it. OR you could send this information to Steam admins.

Documentation for getreviews shows some other parameters - review_type, purchase_type, day_range - and they are marked as Required.
When I add these parameters (except day_range) then code gives me much more reviews.
I stopped code at 25 000 reviews and I didn't check final number.
    payload = {
        'json': 1,
        'cursor': cursor,
        'filter': filter,
        'language': language,
        'num_per_page': 100,
        'filter_offtopic_activity': 0,
        
        #'day_range': 365, 
        'review_type': 'all',
        'purchase_type': 'all',
    }
   
    #print(payload)
    
    url = f"https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/{appid}"
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)


Full working code:
"""
# date: 2024.07.03
# [User Reviews - Get List (Steamworks Documentation)](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews)
"""

import time
from datetime import datetime
import requests
 
def fetch_game_reviews(appid, cursor='*', filter='recent', language='english'):
    """
    Fetch game reviews for a specific Steam game.
 
    Parameters:
    - appid: Steam Application ID for the game.
    - cursor: Cursor for pagination. Use '*' for the first page.
    - filter: Type of reviews to fetch ('recent', 'updated', 'all').
    - language: Language of the reviews ('english', 'spanish', etc.).
 
    Returns:
    - JSON response containing game reviews.
    """
    
    payload = {
        'json': 1,
        'cursor': cursor,
        'filter': filter,
        'language': language,
        'num_per_page': 100,
        'filter_offtopic_activity': 0,
        
        #'day_range': 365, 
        'review_type': 'all',
        'purchase_type': 'all',
    }
   
    #print('payload:', payload)
    
    url = f"https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/{appid}"
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    
    #print('response.status_code:', response.status_code)
    #print('response.text:', response.text)
    
    return response.json()
 
def fetch_reviews_until_date(appid, end_date, filter='recent', language='all'):
    """
    Fetch game reviews for a specific Steam game until a specific date.
 
    Parameters:
    - appid: Steam Application ID for the game.
    - end_date: The end date for fetching reviews (YYYY-MM-DD format).
    - filter: Type of reviews to fetch ('recent', 'updated', 'all').
    - language: Language of the reviews ('english', 'spanish', etc.).
 
    Returns:
    - List of all reviews up until the specified end date.
    """
    
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    previous_cursor = None
    all_reviews = []
    cursors = []
    cursor = '*'
    
    while True:
        response = fetch_game_reviews(appid, cursor=cursor, filter=filter, language=language)
 
        collected_timestamp = int(time.time())
        reviews = response['reviews']
        new_cursor = response.get('cursor')
        cursors.append(new_cursor)
 
        if not reviews or (new_cursor == previous_cursor and cursor != '*'):
            return all_reviews, cursors  
 
        for review in reviews:
            review_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(review['timestamp_created'])
            review['collected'] = collected_timestamp
            review['appid'] = appid
            if review_date < end_date:
                return all_reviews
            all_reviews.append(review)

        # - after loop -
        print('len:', len(all_reviews))
        print('cursor:', response['cursor'])
 
        previous_cursor = cursor
        cursor = new_cursor
 
    return all_reviews, cursors
 
reviews, cursors = fetch_reviews_until_date('1172470', '2020-10-01')


Thank you so much for your comments and your response, I was quite flustered since this is the first time it didn't work properly so as you have pointed out I have missed some additional information! Even though my question was lacking info, thank you very much for the detailed response and your time and interest, it works as intended!!
